# image shows is unreadable format in eclipse drawable folder

Tags: android, image, drawable

[image]

When I add an image into the drawable folder, the image shows in text format although the image name is in lowercase.

I tried all the drawable folders, but the error still doesn't go away.

Comment: Can you please provide a screen shot of your problem?

Comment: Yes I place a screenshot of the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Create a new folder inside res, name it drawable.
- Move birthday.jpg to drawable folder.
- in xml, set attribute `android:background="@drawable/birthday"` to your imageView/layout in which you want your image to be displayed.